# Software that records usage data (button clicks etc) in my software

Tags: library, java, data-visualization, graphs, monitoring

I need a library to embed in my software programs, that would work a bit like the Eclipse Usage Data Collector to be precise.

What i need is a way to get information about the users' button clicks and other GUI interactions.

In the code called by the click I would write something like `UsageDataCollector.AddEvent('click_button')`
and the library would store this data (along with other data that it will harvest alone like the username, the OS, etc) in a file.

I will make by myself a way to actually use this data afterwards.

The Eclipse UDC possesses no API and is too firmly tied to Eclipse RCP to be a solution here.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you tell us more about what you would want the result to look like? A "good API" is something very subjective. Try to tell us what would make such an api "good". Does it need to be very flexible to be fittable to your data or would you want it to produce shiny graphs. If you rank your criteria it makes it easier for answerers to give you a recommendation that fits your need.

Comment: I would like to have something that can efficiently recover data from my programs, without slowing them, I need to log the name of the event, and several information related to its environment ( system informations and such ).
I don't need to make graphs yet, just to fill a database.

Comment: The question should be on-topic now. I improved it and removed the sentence *"I've found things like JAMon API that could work but that i don't really like."* because you did not explain why it is not acceptable. Why don't you love Jamon?

Comment: I like JAMon but my goal is to show my manager many different solutions to choose from.